# How do I use np.where with multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy

How do I specify more than one condition when using np.where() to get the indices of the elements of an array that fulfill **all** of those conditions?

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) 
print(np.where(a > 2 and a < 5))
```

When I say

```
print(np.where(a > 2))
```

I get the indices [2, 3, 4, 5] but now I want to just get [2, 3].

Comment: Is `np.where((a > 2) & (a < 5))` what you want?

Comment: yes thank you! Why does it not work with and?

Comment: the `and` operator cannot be overriden but `&` can, so that's what numpy does. It just doesn't get the chance to define its own `and` as the Python interpreter doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use bitwise operators, `&` for and, `|` for or, and so on.

With your example,

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
np.where((a > 2) & (a < 5))
```

returns

```
(array([2, 3], dtype=int64),)
```